# CSS code to change icon image

Tags: jquery, css, image, icons

I have the code below set to the icon image for a navigation button.  How do I change this code when the button becomes active to insert another icon image?  I am using jquery mobile.  thanks

```
.nav-glyphish-example .ui-btn .ui-btn-inner {
 padding-top: 40px !important; 
}
.nav-glyphish-example .ui-btn .ui-icon { 
width: 30px!important; 
height: 30px!important; 
margin-left: -15px !important; 
box-shadow: none!important; 
-moz-box-shadow: none!important;
-webkit-box-shadow: none!important;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 !important; border-radius: 0 !important; 
}

#home .ui-icon { 
background:  url(glyphish/icons/icons-gray/983-calendarblue@2x.png) 50% 50% no-repeat; 
background-size: 24px 22px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the css dynamically by javascript.
The code below adds a function to `mousedown` event of the elements matching the selector `#home .ui-icon` . and so you can change the backbround image on mousedown event.

### jquery

```
$('#home .ui-icon').mousedown(function(){
  $(this).css('background-image','url(newurl)');
});
```

replace the `newurl` with your own url ( like glyphish/icons/icons-gray/983-calendarblue@2x.png ).

Comment: Add some explanation to this answer and I can give it a +1.

Comment: You can't accomplish the same thing using CSS?

Comment: @jawad thats the answer I am looking for.  I want to be able to do this with just using straight CSS

Comment: @Steven: If the OP is not confused about the "active" (as in the active class given to an HTML element, usually a "li" or "a(anchor)" in a ul mostly for the purpose of navigation to show the "current" page) and the "active" (as in pseudo-class), it can be very well acheived with pure CSS alone and with many methods rangining from chnaging the background-image to changing the list-style-image without the use of JS or JQ. In any case the CSS provided by OP is not clear and also no HTML code is provided.

Comment: @Steven: Please first make it clear which "active" you are reffering to. Aslo your HTML markup will decide the method.

Comment: active meaning that the button is pressed down

Answer (score 2):

```
#home .ui-icon { 
background:  url(normal.png) 50% 50% no-repeat; 
}
#home .ui-icon:active { 
background:  url(active.png) 50% 50% no-repeat; 
}
#home .ui-icon:hover { 
background:  url(hover.png) 50% 50% no-repeat; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about what do you mean exactly with **active** but, take a look at the [:active](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp) selector